# error in bookmark observer, while buidling firefox addon

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, gecko

Okay i have created an observer for bookmark service,
a function is triggered by the observer,when a bookmark item is removed`onItemRemoved: function(id, folder, index)`

Arguments in the function are (id,folder,index)
When i try to access the bookmark URL and title using`getItemTitle(id)` and `getBookmarkURI(id).spec;` i get an NSI ILLEGAL VALUE ERROR.
 the id of the bookmark is an integer (1935 etc)
 Can't see why the bookmark URL is not returned? any clue?

Comment: Since the bookmark is removed, how could the bookmark service satisfy your request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the bookmark item is removed the `id` will no longer be useful.  The [`onItemRemoved`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsINavBookmarkObserver#onItemRemoved%28%29) method takes more arguments than the three that you mentioned though, it takes `aId, aParentId, aIndex, aItemType, aURI, ...` so you can use the aURI argument to get the url that you are interested in.

The better option is to use the `sdk/places/events` module though, like so:

```
const { events } = require('sdk/places/events');

events.on('bookmark-item-removed', ({ data }) => {
  let url = data.url;
  // ...
})
```